# At a microscopic level, how does friction come into exist?

Tags: friction

The simplest answer is that the protuberances on the rough surfaces have inelastic collisions on each other and thus have a macroscopic tendency to impede motion.

Is there any more comprehensive and complete theory about how friction rises?

Is f=μN a theoretical conclusion or an approximate experimental result?

Why is the magnitude of friction LINEARLY proportional to the normal force exerted on the contact surface?

Comment: Ultimately it's all about electrodynamics.

Comment: $F=\mu N$ is purely empirical.

Comment: if you google "microscopic view of friction" a number of references come up